# API Management - how different products can be secured

Tags: azure-api-management

I have an Azure management API instance which has 2 products defined which has apis inside the 2 products. Now Product 1 - inside the portal belongs to Customer 1 (Supported by Support Operator 1) and Product 2 belongs to Customer 2 (Supported by Support Operator 2). What I need is a way to keep the permissions of Support Operator 1 and Support Operator 2 separate. Support Operator 1 - only deals with Product 1 and Support Operator 2 deals with Product 2. Is there anything inside RBAC to give fine grained permissions at API Product level?

Comment: can you give us some more infos? the two products contains the same apis? how do you distinguish the two operator (AAD)?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done via custom roles in RBAC. See more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-role-based-access-control

Comment: Have you got a simple example where the Product "Unlimited"  ca be accessed by just one group

Comment: Not from the top of my head, but read about custom roles in ARM: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/custom-roles The idea is to create custom role with Read(/Write) permissions scoped to specific APIM product.